# Convert a string which is a key value pair to hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I am having problem to manipulating a key value pair of string to hash in ruby.The string is:

```
"specialties":["Corporate Housing","Temporary Housing","Furnished Apartment","Short Term Rentals"],"website":"http://www.demo.com","universalName":"some-corporate-housing","size":"51-200 employees","description":"demo description","industry":"Hospitality","companyType":"Privately Held","companyName":"some Corporate Housing","includeSecondAd":true,"yearFounded":1995,"headquarters":{"city":"Austin","zip":"78759","state":"Texas","street1":"9606 N. Mopac Expressway","country":"United States","street2":"Suite 500"},"homeUrl":"https://www.some.com/company/some-corporate-housing"
```

remember it's an string.Now i would like to make a hash like below:

```
"specialties":["Corporate Housing","Temporary Housing","Furnished Apartment","Short Term Rentals"],

"website":"http://www.demo.com",

"universalName":"some-corporate-housing",

"size":"51-200 employees",

"description":"demo description",

"industry":"Hospitality",

"companyType":"Privately Held",

"companyName":"some Corporate Housing",

"includeSecondAd":true,

"yearFounded":1995,

"headquarters":

  {"city":"Austin",
   "zip":"78759",
   "state":"Texas",
   "street1":"9606 N. Mopac Expressway",
   "country":"United States",
   "street2":"Suite 500"
  },

"homeUrl":"https://www.some.com/company/cws-corporate-housing"
```

I have searched alot and used `split` method of `ruby string` class.Like bellow:

```
# test reffers to the string .
hash = {}
test.split(',').each do |pair|

        key,value = pair.split(/:/) 
        hash[key.to_sym] = value
end
```

this gives me a wrong hash.like bellow:

```
hash["specialties"] #=> "Corporate Housing",
```

as `specialties` is an array it should have all the values but it's only returning the first value.

I can not understand how to convert this string into proper hash.
Please help me guys.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enclose the string inside curly braces `{}` and then parse it using json

```
require 'json'
json_str = "{#{ str }}"
hash = JSON.parse(json_str)
```

Comment: you made my day man thanks so much.I am so dumb such a little trick and its working great.
Thanks again man.

Comment: np. happy to help :)